# Retrieving created_at attribute from timestamp in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am doing a blog project in laravel. i want to retrieve time of a specific post. In laravel there is a function in table called timestamp(). Can I use it for this purpose.I tried several ways but it didn't work,Can anyone help?

post_table:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

home.blde.php file:

```
 <tbody>
                      @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{  $post->title }} </td>
                            <td>Edit</td>
                            <!-- <td>Delete</td> -->

                             <!-- $time= $post->timestamps->('created_at') -->

                            <td>{{ $post->timestamps() }}</td>
                            <!-- <td>{{$time}}</td> -->

                        </tr>



                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: `timestamps()` is not the model instance's function

Comment: what should i do to retrieve the time of the post user posting??!CAn you help please

Comment: I have post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model Post, if you don't define the function `timestamps`, it will not works.

Because `timestamps()` is the method of `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint`,

Take a look at [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_timestamp);

And in your migration, `timestamps()` will generates two columns `created_at` and `updated_at` by default;

I think you just want to call one of them, like:

```php
<td>{{ $post->created_at }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

timestamps() is not Eloquent method and to get both created and updated dates you can do like this:

For Created Timestamp:

```
<td>{{ $post->created_at }}</td>
```

For Updated Timestamp:

```
<td>{{ $post->updated_at }}</td>
```